# MySQL comparing existing records

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I just want to get suggestions about what is the best way to do the following:
I have a csv file, this file contains users and their information. Before I enter that to the MySQL database, I need to compare the email column of the CSV file with the email column in the database, it if exist, I don't insert it, if it doesn't then I insert it. How would I do this process other than manually? I would highly appreciate ideas.

Just to mention, the way I am doing it is so manually (I know it is stupid but I am not that good with SQL) what I do is, I sign in to my wordpress, go to users, and in the search bar I search for every email to make sure it does not exist.

Comment: Upload the csv into MySQL but another table.  Then use that table to find if the email doesn't exist and insert it into the final table

Comment: do you also needs to save stats how many are edited / updated?

Comment: Yes, because the ones that already exist should not be inserted.\

Answer (score 1):

If there's a unique index on the `email` column, you can use `INSERT IGNORE`. This will skip any records that have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the csv to a tempoary table. then insert into the target table by select all the records that is not exist in the target table from source table by using insert into select.